# Is there a way to call some server side code when the "New" button is pressed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

When the `"edit"` button is clicked on my `ASPxGridView`, the **StartRowEditing event** fires. When this occurs, I set a local variable called, `"IsEditing"` So that when **CellEditorIntialize** fires, I can set the datasource for my `comboboxes`. I do this because if the user presses cancel, that `CellEditorInitialize` event fires again and since the `combobox` isn't available, I get a null reference issue.

I need to do the same for the `"new"` button, but there's no `"StartSrowInserting"` event.

Any ideas?

Here's the server code, in C#.

This is the StartRowEditingEvent:

```
protected void gvLocation_StartRowEditing(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxStartRowEditingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsEditing = true; //There's not editing property in this event, so everytime it fires, we'll set this flag to true
        if (e.Cancel) //And we'll only set the flag to false when canceling
            this.IsEditing = false;
    }
```

When I click the "edit" button on the ASPxGridView, this event fires. It will set that variable to true. If the user is cancelling the dialog, it will set it to false.

Then as the controls initialize, the CellEditorInitialize event fires.

```
protected void gvLocation_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;

        if (this.IsEditing) //Only populate fields when editing
        {
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "LocationPK")
                e.Editor.Visible = false; //We don't want LocationPK to be updated
            else if (e.Column.FieldName == "ShalePlay")
            {
                ASPxComboBox combo = (ASPxComboBox)e.Editor;
                mcCommon.Setup(ref combo, true, LookupValuesShalePlay.List, "Description", "PK");
            }
            else if (e.Column.FieldName == "FieldType")
            {
                ASPxComboBox combo = (ASPxComboBox)e.Editor;
                mcCommon.Setup(ref combo, true, LookupValuesFieldType.List, "Description", "PK");
            }
            else if (e.Column.FieldName == "County")
            {
                ASPxComboBox combo = (ASPxComboBox)e.Editor;
                mcCommon.Setup(ref combo, true, LookupValuesCounty.List, "Description", "PK");
            }
            else if (e.Column.FieldName == "State")
            {
                ASPxComboBox combo = (ASPxComboBox)e.Editor;
                mcCommon.Setup(ref combo, true, LookupValuesState.List, "Description", "PK");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I determine which control is which and assign the data sources. If I don't use that flag, when the user cancels the edit, it will throw a null exception. This event also fires when the user clicks "New" or "Cancel", when inserting. But there's no event, that I can find, that fires when clicking the "new" button, before CellEditorInitiliaze fires.

So I need a way to set that flag when the user clicks the "new" and "cancel" buttons, so I can set the flag.

Here's the markup for the ASPxGridView.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView
ID="gvLocation"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="edsLocations"
ClientInstanceName="gvLocation"
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
KeyFieldName="LocationPK"
Width="600px"
OnCellEditorInitialize="gvLocation_CellEditorInitialize"
OnCommandButtonInitialize="gvLocation_CommandButtonInitialize"
OnStartRowEditing="gvLocation_StartRowEditing"
>
    <ClientSideEvents BeginCallback="
                    function(s, e) {loadingPanel.Show();}"
EndCallback="
                    function(s, e) {loadingPanel.Hide();}" />
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="LocationPK" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0" Visible="false">
        <PropertiesHyperLinkEdit TextField="LocationPK" />
    </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LocationName" VisibleIndex="1">
         <DataItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="gvLocation_LinkClick('<%# Container.VisibleIndex %>');"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LocationName") %></a>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="FieldType" VisibleIndex="2">
        <PropertiesComboBox TextField="FieldType" ValueField="FieldType" />
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="State" VisibleIndex="4">
        <PropertiesComboBox ValueField="State" TextField="State" />
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="CountyName" VisibleIndex="3">
        <PropertiesComboBox ValueField="CountyName" TextField="CountyName" ValueType="System.String" DataSourceID="edsCounty" />
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ShalePlay" VisibleIndex="5">
        <PropertiesComboBox ValueField="ShalePlay" TextField="ShalePlay" />
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="6">
        <EditButton Visible="True">
        </EditButton>
        <NewButton Visible="True">
        </NewButton>
    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
</Columns>
<Settings ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" />
<SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
<SettingsLoadingPanel Mode="Disabled" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code please!

Comment: @surajsingh Do you want to see the markup or the server code?

Comment: Both if you can else server code will be good !

Comment: @surajsingh I added the C# code and more details that will hopefully help explain the issue more. I'll add the markup in a minute.

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_InitNewRowtopic
This perhaps?

Comment: @user2025312 That's *almost* perfect. That event does seem to fire prior to the cell initialization. So i can set "IsEdit" during that time. But can't set it to false there. Do you know of an event that fires when the insert is canceled? EDIT: just say CancelRowEditing, I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah it should fire when: 
    an end-user has clicked the Cancel command;
    the ASPxClientGridView.CancelEdit method has been called.

Comment: Thanks guys! Looks like InitNewRow and CancelRowEditing fixes my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'll put my comments as an answer.

Comment: well can you get workaround with this -http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q481679

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ASPxGridView.InitNewRow to catch when the new insert is initiated. You can then use ASPxGridView.CancelRowEditing to catch a cancellation.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_InitNewRowtopic

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CancelRowEditingtopic